# Проблема с добавлением и редактированием записей в SQLite через приложение в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, sqlite

Возникла проблема в добавлении и редактировании записей в SQLite через приложение, сделанное в Qt designer

Мой код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

import sys

from os import path

from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

FROM_CLASS,_ = loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname('__file__'), "untitled.ui"))

import sqlite3

class Main(QMainWindow, FROM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Handel_Buttons()

    def Handel_Buttons(self):
        self.search_2.clicked.connect(self.Get_Data)
        self.check.clicked.connect(self.Level)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.Update)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.Del)
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.New)

    def Get_Data(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cursor = db.cursor()

        command = '''SELECT * from users'''

        result = cursor.execute(command)

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)

        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

        print("Выполнено")

        cursor2 = db.cursor()
        ref_nbr = '''SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT name) FROM users'''
        result_ref_nbr = cursor2.execute(ref_nbr)
        self.lbl_ref_nbr.setText(str(result_ref_nbr.fetchone()[0]))


    def Level(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cursor3 = db.cursor()

        command = '''SELECT id, name, data from users LIMIT 4'''

        result = cursor3.execute(command)

        self.table2.setRowCount(0)

    for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
        self.table2.insertRow(row_number)
        for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
            self.table2.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

    print("Выполнено")


    def New(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cursor = db.cursor()

        command = '''INSERT INTO users (id, name, data, dis, summ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'''

        result = cursor.execute(command)

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)

        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))


    def Update(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        print("Подключен к SQLite")

        id = int(self.id1.text())
        name = self.name1.text()
        data = str(self.data1.text())
        dis = self.dis1.text()
        summ = self.summ1.text()

        row = (name, data, dis, summ, id)

        update_ ='''Update users set name1 = ?, data1 = ?, dis1 = ?, summ1 = ? where id1 = ?'''
        cursor.execute(update_, row)
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()

    def Del(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cursor = db.cursor()

        cursor.execute('DELETE FROM users WHERE id=3')
        db.commit()
        print("Выполнено")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

но выходит ошибка при редактировании:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "..\main.py", line 91, in Update
> id = int(self.id1.text())
> AttributeError: 'QTextEdit' object has no attribute 'text'

и создания:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "..\main.py", line 76, in New
> result = cursor.execute(command)
> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 0 supplied.

Проблема в коде Update и New, не знаю как ее решить. Не могли бы вы подсказать что с этим делать?

Comment: Запускать код из консоли пробовали?

Comment: Да, но ошибка все еще в коде(80 стр) и я не знаю что конкретно там случилось

Comment: Запустите `Debug`(В pycharm Shift-F9) в поле __exception__ будет написана ошибка после выполнения прикрепите её к вопросу

Comment: Пронумеруйте вашу простыню, раз не умеете локализовать проблему, или хотите чтобы я сидел считал где у вас 76 строка?

Comment: Если запустили из консоли то добавьте в вопрос вывод весь из консоли, и скрин консоли тоже, что бы видно было что вы именно творите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В `Update` нужно заменить все `.text()` на `.toPlainText()`
2. В `New` нужно добавить В `result = cursor.execute(command)` Добавляемые значения то есть после параметра `command` добавить кортеж с параметрами id, name, data, dis, summ Как их получить вы лучше должны знать т.к. у меня нет ui файла как то так `result = cursor.execute(command, (id, name, data, dis, summ))`

Comment: Вы лучший, gord1402! Вы решили большую часть моих проблем. За исключением New. Новая запись не отображается в sqlite. Cпасибо вам